# keystoneJS as child_process

Tags: keystonejs

I want to create separate process for sending bulk emails so I kicked off a child process.

```
var cp = require('child_process');
```

Inside that process I am initialising a keystone, but not starting it. because starting will make it listen on HTTP port also.  my intenstion is just to use its Database feature.

Is this possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by   **keystone.mongoose.connect**. Thus I have just initialised the keystone, and mongoose and not initialised the server and express.  This is sufficient for sending bulk emails.

```
 var keystone = require('keystone');

 keystone.init({
    'less': 'public',
    'view engine': 'jade',
    'user model': 'User',
    'emails': '../../templates/emails'
});

keystone.mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/mydb");
keystone.import('../../models');
```